# Angular - How to go to child route?

Tags: angular

In my Angular App I have defined routes:

```
const appRoutes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'news', component: NewsComponent, children: [
        { path: ':id', component: NewsDetailComponent },
    ]},
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

In my NewsComponent ('/news') html file I have *ngFor loop to iterate and generate the news:

```
<div class="news">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3" *ngFor="let n of news" (click)="goToNews(n.id)">
                <div class="single-news">
                    <img [src]="n.photoUrl" [alt]="n.headline">
                    <div class="news-content">
                        <h3>{{ n.headline }}</h3>
                        <p>{{ n.content }}</p>
                        <small>{{ n.author }}, {{ n.date | date }}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

... and my .ts file:

```
goToNews(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['news', id]);
  }
```

The problem is when I click the element, my URL changes, but I stay on the same component I've been for the entire time. How do I navigate to NewsDetailComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a route has child routes, the component that route points to needs to have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. This is what Angular uses to determine where to put the components from the child route.

Alternatively, if your goal is to replace the top-level screen using the details screen, you could restructure your routing scheme as follows to add a top-level route for the detail page.

```
const appRoutes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'news', component: NewsComponent},
    { path: 'news/:id', component: NewsDetailComponent },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` element to your NewsComponent html file, every child route component will be inserted inside the router outlet element.